# How do I access the changed value of the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am doing an exercise of an online course. In this exercise I have a form with 3 inputs and I have to extract them to make a request to a server. My problem is that my JavaScript Code only returns the empty string if I log it in the console, not the changed value. I guess it's accessing the inital value of the html. How can I solve this?

JavaScript Code:

```
// Initial call if the form is submitted
document.querySelector("#compose-submit").onsubmit = send_mail();

// The send_mail function:
function send_mail() {
  let recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value; // Those return the empty string, 
  let subject = document.querySelector("#compose-subject").value;       // although something was written
  let body = document.querySelector("#compose-body").value;             // inside

  fetch("/emails", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: recipients,
      subject: subject,
      body: body
    })
  })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });

  return false;
```

Corresponding html:

```
<h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="compose-submit"/>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line when you are assigning a callback to the onsubmit event, you need to just pass the function name and not call it.

So, changing your first line of code to

`document.querySelector("#compose-submit").onclick = send_mail;`
or
bind your event to the form element to make it work with onsumbit event
`document.querySelector("#compose-form").onsubmit = send_mail;`

should work.

Here's a [JSFiddle as a sample (check console)](https://jsfiddle.net/a2dj4t7r/3/)

Comment: Thank you, what fixed it was changing onsubmit to onclick and passing only the function name. Do you by chance know why I also had to change onsubmit to onclick?

Comment: That's because you're binding onsubmit on the button element, instead it should be on the form element. I've modified the code to make it work with onsubmit too. (I've added preventDefault so that you can see the output in the console).

https://jsfiddle.net/a2dj4t7r/4/

Comment: Thank you! I know understand this a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type to `button` to prevent reloading the page after submitting. And you will keep your values

```js
// Initial call if the form is submitted
document.querySelector("#compose-submit").addEventListener('click', () => {
  send_mail();
});


// The send_mail function:
function send_mail() {
  let recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value; // Those return the empty string, 
  let subject = document.querySelector("#compose-subject").value; // although something was written
  let body = document.querySelector("#compose-body").value; // inside
  
  console.log(recipients);
  console.log(subject);
  console.log(body);

  fetch("/emails", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: recipients,
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });

  return false;
}
```

```html
<h3>New Email</h3>
<form id="compose-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="compose-submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the submit type, when you submit the form, it submits the values of the form to the given url path of your action attribute of the form `<form action="path_to_fetch" method="POST">` and then refreshed the page after. So your javascript code can't catch the values of the form.

One solution is to prevent the form to be refreshed and let your javascript code do the fetching method.

so in your js code, do this:

```js
  // Initial call if the form is submitted
  document.querySelector("#compose-submit").addEventListener("click", send_mail);

  // The send_mail function:
  function send_mail(e) {
    let recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value; // Those return the empty string, 
    let subject = document.querySelector("#compose-subject").value;       // although something was written
    let body = document.querySelector("#compose-body").value;             // inside

    fetch("/emails", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: recipients,
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
        }).finally(() => {
          document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = "";
          document.querySelector("#compose-subject").value = "";  
          document.querySelector("#compose-body").value = "";   
        })

  }
```

Use the finally function to empty the form after submitting the form.

EDIT:
And also change your button type to just button, using the submit type will cause the refresh.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="compose-submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```